# Implementing k nearest neighbours from distance matrix?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to do the following:

Given a dataFrame of distance, I want to identify the k-nearest neighbours for each element. 
Example:

```
  A B C D
A 0 1 3 2
B 5 0 2 2
C 3 2 0 1
D 2 3 4 0
```

If k=2, it should return:

```
A: B D
B: C D
C: D B
D: A B
```

Distances are not necessarily symmetric. 
I am thinking there must be something somewhere that does this in an efficient way using Pandas DataFrames. But I cannot find anything?

Homemade code is also very welcome! :)

Thank you!

Comment: Let me know if my code works

Comment: See below. :) thanks! It works!

Comment: I'm very pre-occupied right now! Can I take more time to explain to you? If you liked my answer, and you're satisfied and it achieved what you want, feel free to TICK it and upvote! Because it really helps me out too!

Comment: @Abhishek Of couse! Really appreicate your help.
I ticked it and tried to upvote it.

Comment: I will give you an explanation, give me some time! I'm involved with another project at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I see it, I simply find `n + 1` smallest numbers/distances/neighbours for each row and remove the 0, which would then give you `n` numbers/distances/neighbours. Keep in mind that the code will not work if you have a distance of zeroes! Only the diagonals are allowed to be 0.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np



X = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1, 3, 2],[5, 0, 2, 2],[3, 2, 0, 1],[2, 3, 4, 0]])

X.columns = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
X.index = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

X = X.T

for i in X.index:

    Y = X.nsmallest(3, i)
    Y = Y.T
    Y = Y[Y.index.str.startswith(i)]
    Y = Y.loc[:, Y.any()]

    for j in Y.index:
        print(i + ": ", list(Y.columns))
```

This prints out:

```
A:  ['B', 'D']
B:  ['C', 'D']
C:  ['D', 'B']
D:  ['A', 'B']
```

Comment: This is super helpful. Thanks! 
Why do you need to transpose it and where does it exclude 0?

Comment: Give me a few moments I will explain! Involved with another question